# Image not displaying mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is the website : http://gravityhub.xyz/y/search/index.php

Try to search : "Item"

It will show the Name, Price, and Image Name. I want it to show the image not the image name.

This is the mysql, I use print $output to show the results

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
$searchq = $_POST['search'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uni_slider WHERE slider_name LIKE '%$searchq%' OR slider_image LIKE '%$searchq%' OR slider_price LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("Could not search");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0){
    $output = 'There was no such results';
}else{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $name = $row['slider_name'];
            $image = $row['slider_image'];
            $price = $row['slider_price'];


            $output .= '<div class="output"> '.$image.' <br/> '.$name.' <br/> '.$price.' <font color="#2ecc71">$</font><br/></div>';
    }
}
```

}

I tried to use `<img src>` but it doesnt work..

Comment: what do you see when you view source?

Comment: $output .= '<div class="output"> <img src="/upload/<?php echo $image ?>">

What do you mean what I see when I view source?

Comment: @Quahogz what do u see when you browse the source code?

Comment: You've just posted a link to your site and source code that details how it is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You probably want to take the site down immediately and fix it, by using prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: You can't `echo` in an assignment. Just concatenate the variable. Also upgrade your driver to `mysqli` or `pdo`. e.g. `$output .= '<div class="output"> <img src="/upload/' . $image . '">';`

Comment: Also, don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: That link posted doesn't look safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$image` has a valid path to an actual image on your server, or somewhere on the internet. The following adjustment to the `while loop` should help:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $name = $row['slider_name'];
            $image = $row['slider_image'];
            $price = $row['slider_price'];


            $output .= '<div class="output"> <img src="/uploads/'.$image.'"> <br/> '.$name.' <br/> '.$price.' <font color="#2ecc71">$</font><br/></div>';
    }
```

As you can see, I've added `<img src="'.$image.'">` to your code.

edit: Based on your comments, you have a directory called "uploads", and in said directory are images. Additionally, the $image variable should contain the image names found in this directory.

Comment: It has in "upload" file. Do I add /upload/ before .$image. ?

Comment: I don't know, do you? What's the path of the images on your server? Where are you storing your images?

Comment: I have an "upload" folder in the main directory

Comment: And in the directory labelled "upload", are there any pictures in there? If so, are these pictures the same names as you'd expect $image to contain?

Comment: Yes exactly what you said

Comment: @Quahogz check my reply.

Comment: See my very minor edit. I've added "/uploads" to the image path. This works, assuming your $image variable contains something like "imagename.jpg". The IMG tag will look for an image under /uploads/imagename.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Change `'.$image.'` to

```
<img src="/y/upload/'.$image.'" alt='.$image.'>
```

make sure that you give the path after image name.

The real path is `/y/upload/` 
and the `$image` gives the image name.

Comment: @Quahogz Its a pleasure to help you :)

Comment: Do you know how to display them next to each other ? If you check the website they just go in a row one under each other

Comment: @Quahogz you want to use `float:left;` its a CSS property. Check this, https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Comment: I do use float: left;

Comment: This is the css code .output {
 float: left;
 width: 100px;
 height: 215px;
    border: 1px solid white;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 background-color: #42454e;
 
}
 but it deosnt change anythign